# Get records from database in table with rowspan

Tags: php, database, html-table

I've try a lot of ways to get this table print as good as it should but I failed.
I know it's simple thing so I hope you help me with it.
Here's my code:

```
<?php
    include('../connect.php');
    $id=$_SESSION['login_user'];
    $sql = "Select CourseName , Studentname from course p natural join student t"; 
    $rs_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection); 

    echo "<center>";
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr> <th>Course Name</th> <th> Students Name</th>  </tr>";

    // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $rs_result )) {
        // echo out the contents of each row into a table
        echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td>' . $row['CourseName'] . '</td>';
        echo "<td rowspan=''> $row[Studentname] </td> ";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>"; 
    echo "</center>";
?>
```

I want to be something like this

```
Course   |  Name   |   Student name  |
Math101  |  john, Mike               |
...
```

Also, is the JOIN query between the two tables CORRECT or not?

The two tables are:
Course ( Course name - Course id )
Student ( Student name - Course id )

Comment: Can You please tell me what the exact output you need

Comment: What does the "Name" column refer to? The "Student" table you described doesn't contain such field. As well as the "Course" table.

Comment: Name = Course name ! .. the output shown course name and student name ( all student names in one row that are taken this course )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

```
$sql ="SELECT cor.CourseName,GROUP_CONCAT(stu.StudentName) AS StudentName
        FROM course AS cor
        LEFT JOIN student AS stu
           ON stu.CourseId = cor.CourseId";
```

And change the the line in below

```
echo "<td rowspan=''>" . $row['Studentname'] . "</td> ";
```

Comment: the rowspan works perfectly! BUT it prints out all student in one row even though the one with different Course id!

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
 echo "<td rowspan=''> $row[Studentname] </td> ";
```

You are accessing the array element improperly. **Studentname** should have single quotes around it like such:

```
 echo "<td rowspan=''>" . $row['Studentname'] . "</td> ";
```

Also, in your query, this may work better:

```
$sql = "SELECT c.CourseName, s.StudentName
        FROM course AS c
        INNER JOIN student AS s
           ON s.CourseId = c.CourseId";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below format

```
SELECT CourseName , Studentname 
    FROM course
    INNER JOIN student
    ON course.id = student.id
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with Your `rowspan` attribute - You need to provide it with the exact number of rows to span through. Anyway, I think it is the `collspan` attribute You want to use, so e.g.

```
echo "<td collspan='2'> {$row['Studentname']} </td> ";
```

which means it will span through 2 columns, thus stundet's name will be both under the `Name` and `Student name` columns.

Is this what You were expecting?

Also I highly recommend not to use `mysql_` functions but learn how to use [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) or at least [PDO](http://php.net/PDO).

Comment: it prints out only one row with the first course name in the database and all student name in the database at the same row!! even the ones with different Course id!

Answer (score 0):

I'm under the impression that you wanted to display a comma-separated list of names of all the students that attend each course, for each separate CourseName. In this case, you could change your SQL query to something like this:

```
SELECT CourseName, GROUP_CONCAT(Studentname SEPARATOR ', ') as names
FROM Course p NATURAL JOIN Student t
GROUP BY CourseName;
```

Comment: yes that's what i meant , i had changed the code to what u give me but it's still gives me an error says : mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: This means that there was an error with the query. Could you just post your CREATE TABLE queries for these 2 tables? My assumptions about your database structure were probably incorrect in some way

Comment: It would be great if you could at least post the string returned by mysql_error() after the query.

Comment: CREATE TABLE Course (CID              number(8) ,
                           Course_name  var(30),
                           CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY (CID)  )

Comment: CREATE TABLE Student (SID              number(8) ,
                           Student_name  var(30), CID  number(8),
                           CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY (SID)  )

Answer (score 0):

Hello please take a look of this answer. [Dynamic rowspan while fetching records from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173455/dynamic-rowspan-while-fetching-records-from-database/30684275#30684275)

I think it might be helpfull.